# Tail recursion happening through the Class Hierarchy

Tags: java, inheritance, recursion, reflection

Hey you people out there,

I'm asking myself the following question. This should be done in Java, but since I don't know how to do it anyway just a concept would help too:
I have the following code:

```
public abstract class A {

   protected enum AType implements AInterface {
     A_VALUE
   }

   public AInterface[] possibleRequests() {
      AInterface types = AType.values();
      return ArrayUtils.concat(types, possibleFurtherRequests());
   }

   public abstract AInterface[] possibleFurtherRequests();

}

public class B extends A {

   protected enum BType implements BInterface {
     B_VALUE
   }

   @Override
   protected AInterface[] possibleFurtherRequests() {
      //Here is my problem.
      return BType.values();
   }
}

public interface AInterface {
}

public interface BInterface extends AInterface {
}
```

What I want to do is have these `possibleRequest`-methods in indefinite depth. They should only be accessible via `A`, I do not and should not know which class the object of type `A` belongs to.

What I mean by indefinite depth is, that say this concept was extended with `C extends B`. I now want to access all values from `A`, `B` and `C`. How do I enforce, that whenever a new subclass is added the programmer is forced to define these `AInterface`-enumerations (optional) and how do I force him to implement a method that is then called recursively up the class Hierarchy (not optional).
I don't need help defining an abstract method, or overriding one. What I want to do is NOT override the existing one and NOT add an abstract method to each inheriting class that gets called.

I honestly don't know how to ask this question but I hope someone out there understands what I mean.
If not leave a comment.

Comment: Why not take the results from `super.possibleRequests()`, create a new `AInterface[] `, then combine the results from `super.possibleRequests()` and your current class' enum `values` and return that?

Comment: You are right, this is a way to do it. That was quite stupid of me. This however doesn't answer the question of how to enforce this behaviour. Another programmer could easily forget to call `super.possibleRequests()`.

Comment: You can't *force* the inheritor to do some behavior, but you can Javadoc it so that people know that you expect them to call `super.possibleRequests`.

Answer (score 0):

Visibility of the methods is important.  You can't force the subclasses to implement the now NOT abstract possibleFurtherRequests, but that is the only method they need.  You also can't force them to call the super method either.  Code reviews work nicely for that.

```
protected enum AType implements AInterface {
    A_VALUE
}

protected enum BType implements BInterface {
    B_VALUE
}

public abstract class A {

    final public AInterface[] possibleRequests() {
        return possibleFurtherRequests();
    }

    protected AInterface[] possibleFurtherRequests() {
        return AType.values();
    }

    protected AInterface[] combine(AInterface[] some, AInterface[] more) {
        AInterface[] combined = new AInterface[some.length + more.length];
        System.arraycopy(some, 0, combined, 0, some.length);
        System.arraycopy(more, 0, combined, some.length, more.length);
        return combined;
    }
}

public class B extends A {

    @Override
    protected AInterface[] possibleFurtherRequests() {
        return combine(super.possibleFurtherRequests(), BType.values());
    }
}

public interface AInterface {
}

public interface BInterface extends AInterface {
}

public void test() {
    AInterface[] result = new B().possibleRequests();
    Stream.of(result).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

And the result is

```
A_VALUE
B_VALUE
```